# No Response in Console?

Tags: c++

So I'm simply making a program that accepts an input and ran into an error; I tried debugging, but there are no messages for me to debug it with when I use std::cout.

```
int main()
{
    try {
        std::ifstream text_file;
        ics::safe_open(text_file,"Enter file name to analyze","C:\\Users\\Xari\\Downloads\\program1\\graph1.txt");
        Graph graph = read_graph(text_file);

        print_graph(graph);

        while (true) {
            std::string input;
            std::cout << "Enter the name of a starting node (enter quit to quit) D: ";
            std::cin >> input;
            std::cout << "INVISIBLE DEBUGGER MESSAGE" << std::endl;
            if (input != "quit")
                std::cout << "Reachable from node name " << input << " = " << reachable(graph, input) << std::endl;
            else
                break;
        }

    } catch (ics::IcsError& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is if I enter "a", "b" the output is fine. If I enter c or higher I get no message response. Even weirder is if I put it right after my input I still get the same issue, which makes no sense.

Comment: The error is most likely in the reachable function. If you used a debugger you could see that.

Comment: Your `Graph` might be corrupt, its functions for traversal flawed, or the `reachable` algorithm flawed.  No way we can know from the code you've posted.  You should post a minimal but complete, compilable program reproducing the problem: in this case you could ditch the input stuff altogether if - after the `print_graph` call, simply calling `std::cout << reachable(graph, "c");` hangs.

Comment: Maybe try using `std::getline(std::cin, input);` instead of `std::cin >> input;`  `getline()` will wait until the user types `ENTER` and then return the entire line typed, whereas `std::cin >>` will stop reading when the user types a whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

check if reachable(graph, input) doesn't run into an infinite loop

Comment: oh so std::cout doesn't list even though it's called before reachable?

Comment: @Xari: you're saying you're not seeing the `std::cout << "INVISIBLE DEBUGGER MESSAGE" << std::endl;` output?  But you are seeing the `std::cout << "Enter the name of a starting node (enter quit to quit) D: ";` prompt and typing something, pressing ENTER?

Comment: Yes. I am seeing the "Enter the name....". When I hit enter it just moves to a new line and doesn't do anything. Only if I enter "a" or "b" will it actually go through reachable. Otherwise, the former happens.

Comment: try commenting the "if (input != "quit") else " block if same thing happens "input c or higher prints nothing" then there is another problem .. else it's as I and @TonyD said

Comment: @Xari: that's the way `std::cin >> input;` is *meant* to work - by default it ignores all whitespace including tabs, linefeeds and carriage returns (i.e. everything your pressing ENTER might put into the stream), until it finds a non-whitespace word to read into `input`.  If you don't want such behaviour, use `if (getline(std::cin, input)) ...` instead.